# Getting error while installing py2exe for python 3.7.9 version

Tags: python, python-3.7, py2exe

I am using Pycharm on Windows 10 and needed to install py2exe package. So I tried to install it with the github repository "https://github.com/lambacck/py2exe-3 ". I don't know what is the problem. If you know please give the fixes.

After sometimes it comes with the output as,

```
It seems that you are using distutils.command.build to add new subcommands. Using distutils directly is considered deprecated, please use setuptools.command.build.

      By 2023-Dec-13, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
      or your builds will no longer be supported.
    
      See https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/ for details.
      ********************************************************************************

!! missing_cmds = set(build.get_sub_commands()) - \_ORIGINAL_SUBCOMMANDS error: 'ext_modules' option must be a list of Extension instances \[end of output\]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully. exit code: 1

See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more up to date version of `py2exe` is hosted in https://github.com/py2exe/py2exe, so try installing from there or with `pip`. Keep in mind, [0.13.0.0 dropped support for Python 3.7](https://github.com/py2exe/py2exe/releases/tag/v0.13.0.0) so you'll have to use an earlier version like 0.12.0.2

To install with pip

`pip install py2exe==0.12.0.2`